# Postgers query - Return data with many to many relationship

Tags: postgresql

I have the following tables: `stores`, `items`,`promotions`, `promotion_stores`,`promotion_items`.

- Each store is linked to promotion and items (the items in the store).
- Each promotion can contain several items.

My goal is to return a JSON list of objects with the following data for a specific store (by `stores.id`):

1. promotion_items.id (from `promotions`)
2. promotion_items,description (from `promotions`)
3. promotion_items.discounted_price (from promotions)
4. The list of items linked to this promotion using `promotion_items`.

The tables look like this:

```
stores: id, name
items: id, store_id, price, other metadata..
promotion_stores: store_id,site_id,promotion_id
promotion_items: promotion_id, item_id
promotions: id, discounted_price, description
```

What I did so far - which is inefficient - using 3 queries:

1. Query all relevant promotions. using: `SELECT promotion_id FROM promotion_stores WHERE store_id = ${branch}`
2. For each promotion ID, query all items at `promotion_items` (another query)
3. For each item ID, query the items table (another query)
   Total of 3 different queries, and they are decoupled from each other.

My goal: Doing it with one query to the DB, more efficiently, without no-SQL code, and build a JSON from the result.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your tables together in one single query, something like :

```
SELECT to_jsonb(p.*) || to_jsonb(i.*) 
  FROM promotion_stores AS ps
 INNER JOIN promotions AS p
    ON p.id = ps.promotion_id
 INNER JOIN promotion_items AS pi
    ON pi.promotion_id = p.id
 INNER JOIN items AS i
    ON i.id = pi.item_id
   AND i.store_id = ps.store_id
 WHERE ps.store_id = ${branch} ;
```

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=987bf01dc0276421cf7dd462dcd423b7).

Comment: Thanks, good start, but I get: ` function to_jsonb(promotions, items) does not exist`

Comment: answer updated to make it working